# golang test assert the nil return from function is failing

Tags: go, testing, null

I am trying to assert a function that returns a nil, but i'm trying to assert nil but the following assertion doesn't make sense.
I am using the `github.com/stretchr/testify/assert`  framework to assert

passes:  `assert.Equal(t, meta == nil, true)`

fails: `assert.Equal(t, meta, nil)`

I am not sure why this makes any sense. could someone help please.

Method being tested:

```
type Metadata struct {
    UserId          string
}

func GetAndValidateMetadata(metadata map[string]string) (*Metadata, error) {
    userId _ := metadata["userId"]
    if userId == "" {
        return nil, errors.New("userId is undefined")
    }
    meta := Metadata{
        UserId:          userId,
    
    }
    return &meta, nil
}
```

testcase:

```
func TestValidation(t *testing.T) {
    metadata := map[string]string{
        "fakeUserId": "testUserId",
    }
    meta, err := GetAndValidateMetadata(metadata)

 assert.Equal(t, meta == nil, true) <--- passes
 assert.Equal(t, meta, nil) <--- fails
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're using the `github.com/stretchr/testify/assert` package, but you may want to be explicit about that in your question, to lift any ambiguity.

Comment: Your sample doesn't compile in the first place. Adding one character makes it ok syntactically, but it's still wrong in that it is missing a `return`.

Comment: Sorry, I have addressed both of your comments.

Comment: use [`assert.Nil`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#Nil) to test for `nil` values

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interface values in Go store a type and a value of that type.

The equal method takes interface{} arguments, so in the second assertion you are comparing an interface value containing type information (*Metadata) and a nil value to an interface without type information and a nil value.

You can force the second interface to also contain a type like so:

```
assert.Equal(t, meta, (*Metadata)(nil))
```

See also ["Why is my nil error value not equal to nil?"](https://go.dev/doc/faq#nil_error) in the FAQ.